# Why does JPA seem to be persisting java.util.Date() 12 hours in advance

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink

There are several variations of this question, but I am struggling to discover a solution to my problem.

I have a JPA, Eclipselink & MySQL based application.  When a record is added or updated in a specific table an "Updated" date field is set to now by using new java.util.Date().

This is the field on my entity class:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "Updated", unique = false, nullable = true)
private Date updated;
```

It is set simply like this:

```
record.setUpdated(new Date());
```

For some reason the dates set in the database always seems to be 12 hours ahead of now?

I have considered AM/PM conversions, timezone issues and checked server times, but all seems ok.

Apologies if this is simple but I am a bit lost!

Comment: Conversion is always done using the timezone returned by `java.util.TimeZone.getDefault()`. Check the value to see if it corresponds to your other settings.

Answer (score 0):

check if -Duser.timezone set in jvm options of server.And check the value of it,if it is set.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, however no timezone is being set.  I would assume therefore that the jvm takes the local system zone?